# Is there a way to set google cloud project permissions to allow contributors to access compute engines, but not create new ones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-iam

I am a project manager, and I want my employees to be able to stop, start and access compute engine instances as admins, but not be able to create new instances.

I have tried messing with permissions, for example I tried the Compute OS Admin Login role, but it still allows them to spin up instances.

Any help is greatly appreciated in finding what permissions are needed to give my employees the access I am looking for them to have.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role) based upon `roles/compute.instanceAdmin` and then remove permissions `compute.instances.create` and `compute.instances.delete`. The [IAM permissions reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) has the whole listing, as there might be further permissions you want to remove. The relevent ones all start with `compute` and end with `create` or `delete`.